# Concatenate symbol with cell array values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbols, cell-array

I have a cell of double {52x1}, I would like to concatenate to each element the symbol ±.

The problem I am having is that sprintf doesn't support the Matlab code \pm for calling the symbol.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pm` is a TeX/LaTeX command, which gives `±` only if the interpreter used by Matlab understands LaTex. This occurs for example in axis labels when the `TickLabelInterpreter` property is set to `'tex'`.

In `sprintf` you can directly use the `±` symbol (code point 177). For example,

```
x = num2cell(rand(5,1)); % cell array of numbers
sprintf('±%f\n', [x{:}])
```

or

```
sprintf([177 '%f\n'], [x{:}])
```

gives

```
ans =
±0.126987
±0.913376
±0.632359
±0.097540
±0.278498
```

Note that I had to transform the cell array of numbers to a numeric vector in order to pass it to `sprintf`.  Consider defining the data directly as a numeric vector to avoid that step.

---

If you want a cell array of strings as result:

```
cellfun(@(t) sprintf([177 '%f\n'], t), x, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis Mendo, it is a good start! And explains why I couldn't make it work. However i was expected to store the output in a cell {1x52}, where each cell is containing the previous cell  value with the symbol "attached". The current solution create a char type variable {1x50}

Comment: See edited answer, last part. That gives a cell array of char vectors